# Webpack dev server with flask html templates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to use Flask to send an html view (template) and React for the front end, but I am having issues setting up the `webpack-dev-server` on the front end. My confusion is, my Flask app is running on port 5000 and sends the view on the port. WebpackdevServer starts on port 8080.

I know webpack dev server serves the bundles out of memory as well, but how do I use this to create Hot Module Replacement. I have read other answers and using webpack watch in conjunction with dev server seems like its not technically correct.

What do I need to do to have my `script` tag that is on my Flask html template to load the bundle file generated by webpack or webpack dev server?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <div id="main"></div>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script defer src="../js/main.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
//webpack dev config
const ab_path = path.resolve(__dirname, '../', 'static/', 'js/');

module.exports = merge.merge(common, {
  entry: ["./src/index.js"],
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.join(process.cwd(), "../static/js")
  },
  // o
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    open: true,
    static: path.resolve(ab_path),
  },
  plugins: [
    new ESLintPlugin()
  ],
  mode: "development"
});
```

I run the command `webpack-dev-server --config /path/to/dev/config but it doesnt seem like it does anything except open a new tab to localhost:8080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Configure Flask to Serve the React App:

   ```
   from flask import Flask, render_template

   app = Flask(__name__)

   @app.route('/')
   def index():
       return render_template('index.html')

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       app.run(debug=True)
   ```
2. Update Your HTML Template:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
       <head>
           <meta charset="utf-8">
           <div id="main"></div>
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
           {% if DEBUG %}
           <script defer src="http://localhost:8080/main.bundle.js" type="module"></script>
           {% else %}
           <script defer src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/main.bundle.js') }}"></script>
           {% endif %}
       </head>
       <body>
       </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. Update Webpack Dev Configuration:

   ```
   const merge = require('webpack-merge');
   const common = require('./webpack.common.js');
   const path = require('path');

   module.exports = merge(common, {
   entry: ['./src/index.js'],
   output: {
       filename: '[name].bundle.js',
       path: path.join(process.cwd(), 'dist'),
       publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/', // Important for webpack-dev-server
   },
   devtool: 'inline-source-map',
   devServer: {
       hot: true,
       open: true,
       static: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'dist'),
   },
   mode: 'development',
   });
   ```
4. Update Webpack Production Configuration:

   ```
   const merge = require('webpack-merge');
   const common = require('./webpack.common.js');
   const path = require('path');

   module.exports = merge(common, {
   entry: ['./src/index.js'],
   output: {
       filename: '[name].bundle.js',
       path: path.join(process.cwd(), 'static', 'js'),
   },
   mode: 'production',
   });
   ```

Comment: Finally got it working. The problem was indeed due to not having the `output.publicpath` as well as not having the correct `src` in my script tag. However, still not too clear on why the `src` value for my script tag is `localhost:8080/main.bundle.js` I thought it would be `localhost:8080/static/js/main.bundle.js`, becuase that is where I put the output.publicpath as and also output.path and static property.